# Voltage divider with Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

I'm working on a project that involves changing a voltage source that modulates from 0-10V to a modulation from 0-5V.
I have tried the simple voltage divider approach with resistors, but the resistive load messes up with the division, so now I'm looking to do a Op Amp voltage divider.
I don't have much experience with Op Amp, could anyone help me how to start on this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Look up "unity gain buffer" and put a conventional voltage divider on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I looked up Unity Gain Buffer application with a general purpose Op. Amp. (UA741); it's requirement for input voltage and output voltage is from 2-11V which does not fit my need (0-5V). Do you know if other Op. Amps will have the same requirement?

Answer (score -2):

Use an op amp with a gain of 1/2.  There are lots of places on the net describing a non-inverting op amp circuit.

Comment: This does not address the OP, since it will transform 0 to 10 volts to 0 to -5.